# Trying to read/run query on bigquery from golang ad get Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found

Tags: go, google-bigquery, access-denied

I'm pretty new in golang and in google cloud.
I try to write the following code and get: (perform a simple query on big-query from golang)
*Error on read %v googleapi: Error 403: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found., accessDenied* 
I read few stackoverflow items about it, but can't find any information for golang.

my code:

```
ctx := context.Background()
projectID := "XXXXXXXXX"
jsonPath:="XXXXX.json"
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID,option.WithCredentialsFile(jsonPath))
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println ("Failed to create client: %v", err)
   return
}
destDatasetID:="dataset1"
destTableID:="table1"
q := client.Query("SELECT * from table1")
q.Location = "EU" // Location must match the dataset(s) referenced in query.
q.QueryConfig.Dst = client.Dataset(destDatasetID).Table(destTableID)
q.AllowLargeResults = true
fmt.Println("prepare complete")
it, err := q.Read(ctx)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("Error on read %v",err)
   return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

code is ok, check your `service account` access rights as:
go to project console -> `service accounts`[image: console[1]]
-> create key along with `big query` access rights [image: access add]
-> finally create key and export is as `json` [image: create key]

few things to mention: 
1. be conservative when giving access to service accounts (minimal access required)
2. re-name your keys in shell accordingly to avoid confusion ex: `bigQueryReadOnly.json`